# Mkdocs site is opened incorrectly

Tags: mkdocs

I've got `mkdocs.yml` file which looks like:

```
site_name: blabla
pages:
  - One page: page2.md
  - Second page: page2.md
  - Navigation: Navigation.md
```

When I open it url is like this: `http://10.2.0.8/blabla/master/Navigation.md` and doesn't work and I get `404 Not Found
nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)` error. If I delete `.md` at the end of url it works fine.

However, on locally it opens like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Navigation/`
does anyone know what's the problem with this?

Comment: You are getting the correct behavior. You should never have `.md` files in the generated site. What do you mean by "When I open it url is like this"? Is that the URL you are typing, or are you clicking on something that is taking you to that URL? If so, what?

Comment: On which webserver (Apache, nginx, ...) are you deploying your files with mkdocs?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [official mkdocs documentation](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/writing-your-docs/), the intended behavior is that `http://10.2.0.8/blabla/master/Navigation.md` does not exist, but rather `http://10.2.0.8/blabla/master/Navigation` as shortcut for `http://10.2.0.8/blabla/master/Navigation/`.

What might have gone wrong in your case is the deployment of the HTML & CSS files. Assuming that your markdown sources are in `~/blabla`, a `mkdocs build --clean` within that directory will create a subdirectory `~/blabla/site/` which you then have to deploy in the respective directory, say `/var/www/html/blabla/`. Under Linux, I suggest a `rsync -r --delete-before ~/blabla/site/* /var/www/html/blabbla/`. In other words: The issue might also be that you simply have not deployed the whole site or at a different place.